# passing string as a condition of a method in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, conditional-statements, whitelist

Is there a way to create a condition through string manipulation. here is the code where I attempted to pass a string as a condition into **include?** method.

```
"hello eveyone in the house".include?(%w('hello' 'world' 'new\ york'    'place').join(" || ").to_s)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An conditional as argument to `include?` is not possible, because `include?` accepts only a string argument.

But you can write something like this:

```
['hello', 'world', 'new york', 'place'].any? { |word|
  "hello everyone in the house".include?(word)
}
```

Or you could generate a regexp from your strings:

```
"hello eveyone in the house".match?(
  /#{['hello', 'world', 'new york', 'place'].join('|')}/
)
```

Comment: nince, but you'll have to use match in Ruby < 2.4  since match? doesn't exist in previous versions

Comment: That is correct `match?` was recently introduced in Ruby 2.4. If you are on an older version just use `match` instead.

Comment: Nice. If you just need a boolean as an answer, the advantage of using `any?` is also that it stops as soon as a string is found.

Comment: Thank it seems I was trying to do something that you can't do.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility would to [split](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-split) the words and use [set intersection](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-26) :

```
sentence  = "hello everyone in the house"
whitelist = %w(hello world new-york place)

found_words = sentence.split & whitelist
p found_words        # => ["hello"]
p found_words.empty? # => false
```

**WARNING :** It only works if the whitelist doesn't contain any string with multiple words. e.g. `new york` in the original question.

For a more robust solution, see @spickermann's answer.

Comment: That doesn't work for whitelisted terms that consist of several words (like `new york` in this example). Because in the sentence `new york`  would be splitted to `['new', 'york']` and that does not intersect with the array `[`new york`]`.

Answer (score 1):

Did some benchmarking to test the speed and to my surprise the first solution of spickerman is the fastest by far in MRI Ruby 2.3.0 on a windows box, followed by intersection while my own solution with Regexp.union ends up last :(

```
require 'benchmark' 

s = "hello everyone in the house"
a = ['hello', 'world', 'new york', 'place']

N = 10_000

Benchmark.bmbm do |x| 
  x.report("Union         ") { N.times { s.match(Regexp.union(a)) }}
  x.report("Union and scan") { N.times { s.scan(Regexp.union(a)) }}
  x.report("Interpollation") { N.times { s.match(/#{a.join('|')}/)}}
  x.report("intersect     ") { N.times { s.split & a }}
  x.report("block         ") { N.times { a.any? { |word| s.include?(word)}}}
end 

Rehearsal --------------------------------------------------
Union            0.110000   0.000000   0.110000 (  0.116051)
Union and scan   0.124000   0.000000   0.124000 (  0.121038)
Interpollation   0.110000   0.000000   0.110000 (  0.105943)
intersect        0.015000   0.000000   0.015000 (  0.018456)
block            0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.001908)
----------------------------------------- total: 0.359000sec

                     user     system      total        real
Union            0.109000   0.000000   0.109000 (  0.111704)
Union and scan   0.125000   0.000000   0.125000 (  0.119122)
Interpollation   0.109000   0.000000   0.109000 (  0.105288)
intersect        0.016000   0.000000   0.016000 (  0.017283)
block            0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.001764)
```

Comment: Try putting "helllo" at the end of `a` to see how that affects the results. As it is, @spickerman's method bails after processing "hello", whereas the others keep going.

Comment: You compile `N` regular expressions, move the `Regexp.union` out of the loop and it might be fastest.

Comment: I am not surprised by this outcome. Building regexp and starting the "regexp engine" is extremely expensive compared to simple string operations and string comparisons. It is only worth it for simple use cases like this, the longer the texts, the more complex the condition or the more often you reuse the same regexp the more a regexp pays off.